# grouping data in ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I'm trying to group data by the date it was created (month and year). How can I iterate through ObservableCollection of Groups, if the specific group already exists and if so, add the data to the group with the same month-year ID? If the group with the date doesn't exist, the program should create a group and add the data as a first item. I have two data model classes - Data and Group:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public static DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

    private string ID = Date.ToString("MM/yyyy");
}

public class Group
{        
    public ObservableCollection<Data> DataGroup { get; set; }
    private string ID;

    public Group(string id)
    {
        ID = id;
    }
}
```

Heres how i imagined the AddData method to work:

```
public async Task AddData(Data data)
    {
        var id = data.ID;
        Group newGroup = new Group(id);
        foreach (Group group in _groups)
        {
            if (/*what kind of condition should i put here?*/)
            {
                if (group.ID == id)
                {
                    newGroup.DataGroup.Add(data);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _groups.Add(newGroup);
                newGroup.DataGroup.Add(data);
            }
        }            
        await saveDataAsync();               
    }
```

now, is there a way to check if the _groups collection have an item equal to newGroup (same ID)?

Comment: `newGroup == group` and implement the `==`-opterator. Or use `.Equals` instead.

Comment: The use of `async void` is highly discouraged (except for event handlers), use `async Task` instead.

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht won't this just add newGroup to the collection in every iteration untill it reaches the equal group?

Comment: I need a condition that would tell if the group exists, (preferable before the iteration starts) not if its equal to the group in current iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

above @frankJ answered my question with a very good and clean method using lambda expression, although it FirstOrDefault method doesn't accept null reference. I've came up with something like this:

```
public async Task AddData(Data data)
    {
        var id = data.ID;
        Group newGroup = new Group(id);
        bool checkIfExists = false;

        foreach (Group group in _groups)
        {
            if (group.ID == newGroup.ID)
            {
                checkIfExists = true;
                break;
            }               
        }

        if (checkIfExists)
        {
            foreach (Group group in _groups)
            {
                if (group.ID == id)
                {
                    group.DataGroup.Add(data);
                }
            }       
        }
        else
        {
            newGroup.DataGroup.Add(data);
            _groups.Add(newGroup);
        }

        await saveDataAsync();               
    }
```

Comment: The line `if (group.ID == newGroup.ID)` in your code will just throw the same `NullReferenceException` you just simply have to check for `null` values in my solution e.g. `... _groups.FirstOrDefault(f => f != null && f.ID == id);`

Comment: well, actually it didn't. It seems like the only thing that didn't accept the null reference in this case, is the FirstOrDefault method, and the thing was to just not use it, and it actually works this way with no problems at all. But thanks for Your help anyway ;)

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to get an existing group via [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v=vs.110).aspx). If none exists, create one and add it to the `_groups` collection. Either way after this you will have the relevant reference to the group and just can add the data.

Example:

```
public async Task AddData(Data data)
{
    var id = data.ID;

    //Will return null if no such group exists
    Group relevantGroup = _groups.FirstOrDefault(f => f != null && f.ID == id);
    if(relevantGroup == null)
    {
        //Didn't have one so we add the a new group and assign it to the variable
        relevantGroup = new Group(id);
        _groups.Add(relevantGroup);
    }
    //This now always references the correct group, just add your data item
    relevantGroup.Add(data);

    await saveDataAsync();               
}
```

EDIT: Added a `null` reference check.

Comment: actually this gives me the "value cannot be null" exception. it seems like the FirstOrDefault doesn't accept null reference.